# How to create a rectangle shape dynamically using float values?

Tags: android, android-view, android-canvas, android-graphics

I want to dynamically create rectangle shape by using float values from server. The shapes should be precise like if any value is 25.2 and another is 25.3 then the 25.3 one should look bigger like we see in charts. So is there any way to achieve this? Here's the image:

[image]

I was trying to change the view size by using this:

```
itemView.tv_value.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height)
```

But this seems to be accepting integer values only and if float converted to int using double then it will round off to the nearest number and it won't work.

How to achieve this either by using canvas or views?

Comment: How far you try? You code dose not make seance..

Comment: tv_value is a view of some DynamicWidth* FixedHeight dimension now i am trying to set the width of this view using float values

Comment: are you using RecycleView?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `width` or `height` of any view can not be `float` value.

You can set `int` value based on **pixel of screen** and **float value** ratio.

Layout for adapter to generate graph...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
        android:id="@+id/lo_dynamic_view_container">

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_chart_value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Generate Ration

```
private float getRatio(int width, float value, float highestValue){
   float result = 0;
   result = ( (float)width/highestValue) * value;
   Log.e("Result", "width: "+ width +" "+(int) Math.floor(result)+"");
   return result;
}
```

Combine Activity and adapter calss

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

ArrayList<Data> listData = new ArrayList<>();
BarChartAdapter barChartAdapter;

int[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_bar_chart);

    listData.add(new Data(8.0f,Color.GREEN));
    listData.add(new Data(4.0f,Color.CYAN));
    listData.add(new Data(2.0f,Color.MAGENTA));

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    barChartAdapter = new BarChartAdapter(listData);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(barChartAdapter);
}

public class BarChartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BarChartAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Data> listData = new ArrayList<>();

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        LinearLayout layout;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_chart_value);
            layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lo_dynamic_view_container);
        }
    }

    public BarChartAdapter(ArrayList<Data> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
    }


    @Override
    public BarChartAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View v = (View) LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.barchart_layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        holder.textView.setText(listData.get(position).value+"");

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        width = width - (100/width)*80;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        tv.setWidth((int) Math.floor( getRatio(width, listData.get(position).value,getHighestValue(listData))));
        float redious [] = { 0, 0, 8.3f, 8.5f, 8.2f, 8.9f, 0, 0 };
        ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable (new RoundRectShape(redious,null,null));
        shape.getPaint().setColor(listData.get(position).color);

        //shape.getPaint().setColor(colors[new Random().nextInt((colors.length-1) - 0 + 1) + 0]);
        //shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);

        tv.setBackground(shape);
        holder.layout.addView(tv);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
}



private float getRatio(int width, float value, float highestValue){
    float result = 0;
    result = ( (float)width/highestValue) * value;
    Log.e("Result", "width: "+ width +" "+(int) Math.floor(result)+"");
    return result;
}

private float getHighestValue(ArrayList<Data> listData){
    float result = 0.0f;

    if(listData!=null){
        if(listData.size()>0){
            for (int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {
                result = listData.get(i).value>result?listData.get(i).value:result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}


class Data{
    float value;
    int color;

    public Data(float value, int color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
}
```

Screen Shoot [image]

[Full Project link on GitHub](https://github.com/enamul-java/CustomBarChart)

Comment: i tried your code, there are two problems: 1. It makes the same width line for values like 8.2 and 8.4, it seems to be rounding off or not.

Comment: 2.) This code doesn't work for negative values, the negative value gets displayed but no negative bar is displaying.

Comment: Actually I ask you before. Your code doesn't say every thing you want!!  What is you scenario? How I know you are going to add negative value. Just I try to understand your fundamental problem... now it's up to you... enhance as you want...

Comment: 8.2 and 8.4 is same because of you device you use for debug. Suppose your screen width in pixel is 800 px. Your highest value is 20 so, unit is 800/20=  40 px. here to show 8.2 need 8.2*40 = 328 px and for 8.4 is 336 px. Now difference is 336-328= 8px. If your device DPI is high then it will show same length. If you don't know about DPI, PIX see https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.

Comment: You better use third party library for showing graph.. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart this lib will great for you....

Comment: i have figured out something else using that library, but thank you for your great efforts, i have already upvoted your answer :)